# Replace duplicate senteces in text

Tags: java, string, text

I have a big list of sentences, some of them are similar to each other but a bit different.
something like:

[word1] [word2] [word3]

[word1] [word3]

[word1] [word2] [word3] [word4]

I would like to delete "duplicates" and get only one sentence.
Just asking if it is possible in java?

Comment: Not sure I'm following. What is the expected output?

Comment: I have list of 10k sentences similar do each other and I would like to get ~1k without duplicates(some of them have 5 copies, some 20) one for each sentence

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < words.length; j++)
    {
         if (words[i].equals(words[j]))
         {
         if (i != j)
         words[i] = "";

         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Better approach is to create a new array with the result instead of overwriting the current array with empty string

Answer (score 0):

add the list to a Set.. set will not have duplicates..  refer below code..

```
    List<String> collectionWithDuplicates = new ArrayList<>();

    Set<String> collectionWithoutDuplicates = new HashSet<>();

    collectionWithoutDuplicates.addAll(collectionWithDuplicates);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8

```
 List<String> newList = oldList.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
```